# Error in `[.default`(data, , pos) : subscript out of bounds using predict function in R

Tags: r, rpart

I am banging my head against the wall with this one. I have made predictions from a decision tree, my predictor variables are exactly the same dimensions in both the prediction object and my training data dataset, yet when I try to construct a Confusion Matrix I get the warning "Error in `[.default`(data, , pos) : subscript out of bounds". I cannot seem to be able to work it out.

```
library(caTools)
library(caret)
library(rpart)

set.seed(123) 
sample = sample.split(df_clean, SplitRatio = .75)
train1 = subset(df_clean, sample == TRUE)
test1  = subset(df_clean, sample == FALSE)
dim(train1)
dim(test1)

#training DT
set.seed(456)
dt <- rpart(my_label ~ activePower+activePowerDelta+reactivePower+voltage+
                         phase+transient8+transient10+harmonicDelta1+harmonicDelta2+
                         harmonicDelta8, data=train1, method = "class")

predictions_dt <- predict(dt, test1, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(predictions_dt, test1$my_label)
```

Both predictions_dt and test one are in the same format of 24,020 entries - factors with the same number of levels - eg. "+fridge, +fridge+microwave, +fridge+oven"

Thanks for your help!

adding output from checking levels:

```
str(df_clean$my_label)
df_clean$my_label <- as.factor(df_clean$my_label)
levels(df_clean$my_label)
levels(df_clean$my_label)[1]
```

levels(df_clean$my_label)
 [1] ""                                                   "+fridge"
 [3] "+fridge+kettle"                                     "+fridge+kettle+microwave"
 [5] "+fridge+kettle+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer"           "+fridge+kettle+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer+microwave"
 [7] "+fridge+kettle+washer_dryer"                        "+fridge+kettle+washing_machine+washer_dryer"
 [9] "+fridge+microwave"                                  "+fridge+shower"
[11] "+fridge+shower+kettle"                              "+fridge+shower+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer"
[13] "+fridge+shower+washer_dryer"                        "+fridge+shower+washing_machine+washer_dryer"
[15] "+fridge+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer"                  "+fridge+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer+microwave"
[17] "+fridge+vacuum"                                     "+fridge+vacuum+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer"
[19] "+fridge+vacuum+washer_dryer"                        "+fridge+vacuum+washing_machine+washer_dryer"
[21] "+fridge+washer_dryer"                               "+fridge+washer_dryer+microwave"
[23] "+fridge+washing_machine+washer_dryer"               "+fridge+washing_machine+washer_dryer+microwave"
[25] "+kettle"                                            "+shower"
[27] "+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer"                         "+washer_dryer"

Adding output from dput(head(df_clean))

```
dput(head(df_clean))
structure(list(id = c(74589930L, 74589012L, 74588101L, 74587582L, 
74587236L, 74586372L), type = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L), activePower = c(78L, 
80L, 77L, 43L, 143L, 146L), activePowerDelta = c(-2L, 1L, 32L, 
-100L, -3L, -7L), reactivePower = c(-38L, -38L, -37L, -22L, 143L, 
142L), voltage = c(223.389, 224.258, 225.127, 224.258, 223.389, 
223.389), phase = c(-25.6, -25.3, -25.6, -27, 44.6, 43.9), transient7 = c(0.567, 
0.562, 0.584, 0.282, 0.914, 0.924), transient9 = c(0.567, 0.562, 
0.57, 0.29, 0.914, 0.924), transient10 = c(0.567, 0.562, 0.572, 
0.282, 0.914, 0.924), harmonicDelta1 = c(90L, 21L, 235L, 1183L, 
82L, 128L), harmonicDelta7 = c(127L, 64L, 77L, 14L, 39L, 36L), 
    harmonicDelta9 = c(148L, 85L, 62L, 4L, 41L, 42L), timestamp = c("2018-01-21 23:58:08+00:00", 
    "2018-01-21 23:55:28+00:00", "2018-01-21 23:52:46+00:00", 
    "2018-01-21 23:51:03+00:00", "2018-01-21 23:49:59+00:00", 
    "2018-01-21 23:47:19+00:00"), my_label = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "+fridge", "+fridge+kettle", 
    "+fridge+kettle+microwave", "+fridge+kettle+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+kettle+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer+microwave", "+fridge+kettle+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+kettle+washing_machine+washer_dryer", "+fridge+microwave", 
    "+fridge+shower", "+fridge+shower+kettle", "+fridge+shower+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+shower+washer_dryer", "+fridge+shower+washing_machine+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer", "+fridge+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer+microwave", 
    "+fridge+vacuum", "+fridge+vacuum+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+vacuum+washer_dryer", "+fridge+vacuum+washing_machine+washer_dryer", 
    "+fridge+washer_dryer", "+fridge+washer_dryer+microwave", 
    "+fridge+washing_machine+washer_dryer", "+fridge+washing_machine+washer_dryer+microwave", 
    "+kettle", "+shower", "+tumble_dryer+washer_dryer", "+washer_dryer"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, why is transient8 missing from df_clean?

Comment: My fault, an error when inputting my features for the decision tree. I have now corrected this and used the correct features which match df_clean and test1 train1 but still the same result with the Confusion Matrix

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Now with your sample data I can reproduce your code. When you look at your `predictions_dt` there are way less rows than in your `test1$my_label`. That is because you have incomplete cases (rows full of NA) that should be removed prior the training.

Short answer : remove the target label from your test1 sample.

```r
predictions_dt <- predict(dt, test1[,-which(names(test1)=="my_label"))], type = "class")
```

--- **Past answer**

I found this error looking at the examples of the help of `rpart` which are quite interesting :

```r
library(rpart)
# ?rpart # to use package help and try working examples.
set.seed(123) 
# sample = sample.split(kyphosis, SplitRatio = .75) # part of an unspecified package
df_clean <- kyphosis

ind_split <- sample(1:nrow(kyphosis), size = floor(.75*nrow(df_clean)), replace = FALSE)
train1 <- df_clean[ind_split,] 
test1  <- df_clean[-ind_split,]
dim(train1)
dim(test1)

fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = train1)
fit2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = train1,
              parms = list(prior = c(.65,.35), split = "information"))
fit3 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
              control = rpart.control(cp = 0.05))
par(mfrow = c(1,2), xpd = NA) # otherwise on some devices the text is clipped
plot(fit)
text(fit, use.n = TRUE)
plot(fit2)
text(fit2, use.n = TRUE)

# Prediction
pred <- predict(object = fit, newdata = test1[, -1],
        type = c("vector", "prob", "class", "matrix"),
        na.action = na.pass)

# Evaluate
table(pred, test1$Kyphosis)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still no joy. I am wondering if the root cause is something to do with levels. When I look at my levels the first seems empty, ... "". I don't know how to address or remove this. I will add an example in my original post.

Comment: It might also be due to levels in test1 not present in train1 (or vice & versa). But without your data provided one can't be sure.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(df_clean)` ?

Comment: Thanks for helping cbo, I have added the output of dput(head(df_clean)) in my original post.